# Increasing opacity at the border of the circle in react native expo

Tags: android, ios, react-native, svg, expo

I tried to create View with increasing opacity with "expo-linear-gradient" library, but I can't create correсt border like on this image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZCWO.png)

I tried to use svg, but it doesn't work:

```
<svg width="96" height="96" viewBox="0 0 96 96" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M48 88C70 88 88 70 88 48C88 26 70 8 48 8C26 8 8 26 8 48C8 70 26 88 48 88Z" stroke="url(#paint0_angular_1041_1651)" stroke-width="2.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
<defs>
<radialGradient id="paint0_angular_1041_1651" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(48 48) rotate(90) scale(40)">
<stop stop-color="#7633FF"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#7633FF" stop-opacity="0"/>
</radialGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
```

and expo-linear-gradient doesn't have necessary effect

Answer (score 0):

That's a conic gradient, which is hard to duplicate in regular SVG - but you can copy a generic image of a conic gradient and use it as a filter input to get what you want done. Here's an example:

```html
<svg width="400px" height="400px">
  <defs>
  <filter id="conic-fade" >
    <feImage width="360" height="360" xlink:href="https://assets.codepen.io/32648/conicgradient.JPG"/>
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0   1 0 0 0 0   1 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 1 0"/>
    <feColorMatrix type="luminanceToAlpha"/>
    <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    <feComposite operator="in" in="SourceGraphic"/>
  </filter>
  </defs>
  
    <g filter="url(#conic-fade)">
        <circle stroke="purple" stroke-width="4" fill="none" cx="200" cy="200" r="150"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code doesn't work in react native project. I have an error "Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `feImage` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter." and when I try to change first letter on the capital I have an error "Cannot find name 'FeColorMatrix'."

Comment: Ah apologies - apparently SVG filters aren't supported in react native (still!)